# Interpolation of data to a staggered grid

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have data on 25 points like this:

Z=

```
0.6840    0.7208    1.0240    1.0293    0.7713
0.8602    0.9089    1.3414    0.8970    0.7107
0.8869    0.8282    1.7015    0.9967    0.9243
0.7469    0.9534    1.5206    1.2741    1.0281
0.8952    1.1554    0.8525    1.2993    0.9890

pcolor(Z)=
```

[image]

Pcolor interpolates the data to form the colours but doesn't give me the value of each new square.  I'd like to do this manually via `interpolation`:

I'd like to average these pink points to make an interpolated value at the centre of each square ie the blue numbers.

[image]

This doesn't seem to do that.

```
x=1:5;
y=1:5;

xi=0.5:1:5;
yi=0.5:1:5;
ZI=interp2(x,y,Z,xi,yi);
```

gives:
ZI =

```
0.8918    1.0778    0.8194       NaN       NaN
0.9084    1.3375    0.8967       NaN       NaN
1.0035    1.5858    0.8852       NaN       NaN
1.1633    1.4250    1.0040       NaN       NaN
   NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Any pointers would be appreciated,
Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear if you want an supersampled matrix or just the interpolated values. If the later, you could simply do:

```
 Z = [ 0.6840 ,   0.7208   , 1.0240   , 1.0293  ,  0.7713;
       0.8602  ,  0.9089  ,  1.3414  ,  0.8970  ,  0.7107;
       0.8869  ,  0.8282  ,  1.7015  ,  0.9967  ,  0.9243;
       0.7469  ,  0.9534  ,  1.5206  ,  1.2741  ,  1.0281;
       0.8952  ,  1.1554  ,  0.8525  ,  1.2993  ,  0.9890];

 Z1 = (Z(1:end-1,1:end-1)+Z(2:end,1:end-1)+Z(1:end-1,2:end)+Z(2:end,2:end))/4

ans =

   0.79348   0.99877   1.07293   0.85208
   0.87105   1.19500   1.23415   0.88218
   0.85385   1.25093   1.37322   1.05580
   0.93773   1.12047   1.23662   1.14762
```

Or if you really want to use the `interp2` function: (I use a 5x4 matrix so that it's more instructive)

```
 Z = [ 0.6840 ,   0.7208   , 1.0240   , 1.0293  ,  0.7713;
       0.8602  ,  0.9089  ,  1.3414  ,  0.8970  ,  0.7107;
       0.8869  ,  0.8282  ,  1.7015  ,  0.9967  ,  0.9243;
       0.7469  ,  0.9534  ,  1.5206  ,  1.2741  ,  1.0281]

   interp2(Z,[1:4 ]+0.5,[1:3]'+0.5) 

   0.79348   0.99877   1.07293   0.85208
   0.87105   1.19500   1.23415   0.88217
   0.85385   1.25093   1.37322   1.05580
```

(tested in Octave)

Comment: Thank you!  Both work nicely.  What is a supersampled matrix by the way?  Wiki has a reference to antialiasing...

Comment: If you regard the matrix as a 2D-signal, the you could speak of supersampling, as for any signal (change to a smaller discretization step). Linear interpolation is one of the several supersampling procedures, rather basic.